# Is it recommended to use additional addons to improve privacy?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, firefox, plugin

Would security improve using Firefox extensions with the Tor Bundle (as Ghostery, HTTP Everywhere, Disconnect, DoNotTrackMe, Adblock Plus, Privdog... etc)?

Comment: Your question seem a bit broad too me. I think it is quite hard to give a general and helpful answer to this question. Maybe you can write what attacker you have in mind, how you define security etc. So narrowing down your question helps to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of the Tor project is *anonymity*. Your physical location and your operating system are obscured. Unless you provide personal data you will be anonymous.

Strictly speaking, *privacy* is maintained by Tor's SSL support. Having an encrypted link between your browser and the server you are communicating with is what maintains your *privacy*.

That said, plugins might increase your *privacy* by limiting interaction with adservers or tracking devices, but they diminish your *anonymity* by changing how your browser behaves. (See this stackexchange's [fingerprint](/questions/tagged/fingerprint) tag for related questions or check out the [EFF's panopticlick project](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)).

Given the Tor's goal of providing anonymity, the standard answer to your question is to recommend that you not install additional plugins.